# Python Pandas: NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python, pandas

Ok, this is my first Python Pandas program and I'm having a hard time figuring out what the column name is so I can reference it in a function call.

Below is my code. parseDeviceType is calling a function to parse useragentstring. But when I call it using what I think the column name is, I get an error that name is not defined:

```
df = pd.read_csv('user_agent_strings.txt',index_col=None, na_values=['NA'],sep=',')
dt=parseDeviceType(user_agent_string)
print df.columns

NameError: name 'user_agent_string' is not defined
Index([u'user_agent_string'], dtype='object')
```

And here's the  header and first row of data from the input file containing the useragentstrings:

```
"user_agent_string"
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
```

Can you help me understand how to reference the column name in the `dt=parseDeviceType(user_agent_string)` call? I'd like to also know how to reference it by column number if that is possible in a call to a function.

Thanks

Comment: Should `user_agent_string` be a string? Like: `dt=parseDeviceType('user_agent_string')`.

Comment: Hi: I'm trying to pass a column name. Wouldn't putting the user_agent_string in quotes imply that I'm passing a literal rather than a variable?

Comment: @Jazzmine try df. user_agent_string

Comment: As your code is now that variable doesn't seem to exist ;)

Comment: As you've not shown the code for `parseDeviceType` my guess is that you are trying to pass a variable name rather than a string for column selection from your df, have you tried what figs has suggested and wrapping quotes around `user_agent_string`?

Comment: My apologies figs  and I guess that's my welcome to pandas. Passing the variable name in single quotes worked just fine. It only did one row though, do i need a for loop to have it iterate through the entire dataframe? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Import pandas package to read data

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('user_agent_strings', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'],sep=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to understand is the error message you are seeing:

`NameError` is a Python exception and is not related to Pandas in this case. You can get exactly the same error by trying to use any name which the interpreter doesn't know about:

```
>>> b = a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

It is important to know that very few Python commands will "magically" create names. To create a name, you would almost always need an assignment (`name = ...`). So as a general rule if you you haven't done this, `name` will not exist. In your code, the name you have created is `df`, so you will need to go through that to get to your data.

You can use two different ways to access the data in the dataframe, which are equivalent: `df['user_agent_string']` or `df.user_agent_string`. I recommend trying this out in an interactive environment so that you can see the results before passing it to a function.

I'm also going to guess that your function `parseDeviceType` only does this for one string (based on the comments), but you want to call this function on every item in your file. To do this you would need [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
parsed_types = df.user_agent_string.apply(parseDeviceType)
```

To access columns by number instead of name (which I don't recommend), you can use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html). This allows you to access all the rows (`:`) and the first colum (`0`) from the dataframe object:

```
user_agent_string = df.iloc[:, 0]
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to remove .txt from your file name might help.
Like the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('user_agent_strings', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'],sep=',')
```

Comment: Could you please provide some explanation as to why this is correct?

Answer (score -2):

In here , you didnt import the pandas

```
import pandas as pd
pd = pd.read_csv('anythinf.csv')
```

When you save your file and open later this time you will get same error so you need to restart your project and compile your code from the start ...if you use jupyter notebook..
you can easily erase all the errors